# How could I add a drop down menu to this navbar?

Tags: html, css

Hey guys, I have created a navbar and I'm wondering if I can create a drop-down menu for the entertainment tab to give two links, music and movies. Could you please help?

Here's the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="index.php">Homepage</a></li>
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="classes.php">Classes</a></li>
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="calendar.php">Calendar</a></li>
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="news.php"  >News</a></li>
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="creative.php" >Creativity</a></li>
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="groups.php" >Groups</a></li>
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="entertainment.php" >Entertainment</a></li>
  <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="aboutus.php" >About Us</a></li>
  </div>
```

here's the css for the navbar class:

```
ul.navbar
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
}
li.navbar
{
float:left;
}
a.navbar:link,a.navbar:visited
{
display:block;
width:143px;
font-weight:bold;
color:white;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
a.navbar:hover,a.navbar:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One classic way is with  [Suckerfish dropdowns](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) (no javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/qHKbc/2/

The jquery shows and hides the next submenu when you roll over an element with the class .menu-header

```
    $('.menu-header').hover(
      function() { $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideToggle(100); },
      function() { $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideToggle(100);  }
    );
```

The sub-menu is hidden with css

```
ul#navbar li ul.sub-menu { display:none; position:absolute; z-index: 100; }
```

I would look into using hoverIntent, the jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example [**http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/KZchD/**](http://jsfiddle.net/huhu/KZchD/) without javascript.

```css
#access {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: #98bf21;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 700px;
}
#access .menu {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 928px;
}
#access .menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#access .menu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#access a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#access ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    z-index: 99999;
}
#access ul ul li {
    min-width: 180px;
}
#access ul ul ul {
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#access ul ul a {
    background: #7A991A;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 160px;
    height: auto;
}
#access li:hover > a, #access ul ul :hover > a {
    background: #7A991A;
    color: #fff;
}
#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="access">
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="classes.php">Classes</a></li>
      <li><a href="calendar.php">Calendar</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="creative.php">Creativity</a></li>
      <li><a href="groups.php">Groups</a></li>
      <li><a href="entertainment.php">Entertainment</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="music.php">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="movies.php">Movies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```